# Custom button component protected property

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, mxml

In my custom button component, I want to get a handle on the textField (The internal UITextField object that renders the label) in the Button so I can modify some properties on it. It exists as a protected var in Button.as
How can I do that in my mxml component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you extend Button then you have access to all protected properties of the Button class.